# Elder person with hypertension flying first time. Anything we should know beforehand?

Tags: air-travel, health

My grandmother, who is in her 70s, would like to visit me. It is a 2.5 hour flight.

The problem is that the last time she flew was in her teens. Now she also has hypertension.

There will be some family members with her during the flight. But my worry is if the flight will have any impact on her health? Has anyone been in this position and could share some advice?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a question that she will have to ask her doctor.  We're not in a position here to offer medical advice.

Comment: If she *knows* she has hypertension, most likely she is taking medication for it already. In that case, consult her doctor. Many people with hypertension *don't* know they have it, until it causes another medical problem. It's not clear from your question whether she will be taking out travel insurance, but if she does don't forget that she may need to declare this as a pre-existing medical condition.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contributions. Doctor just said yes - she's fit to fly, without getting into other details. I wanted to hear some other advice, perhaps from your own experience, especially considering this person hasn't flown for 60+ years. The accepted answer provides sufficient reassurance for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can not give you a definitive answer here, it totally depends on her situation and the best person who can give such an advice is her doctor.

If she is a person who has a history of a sudden health problems related to hypertension or any other sickness, it is best to pay a visit to a doctor to assess her overall health situation before flying.

Anyway, let's assume that she is in a stable situation and she has her meds with her, then there is nothing to worry about. 2.5 hrs is a short flying time and I am not aware of any negative sides of flying on people with hypertension. I see them flying all the time and I know that because of the number of low sodium meals on each flight (cabin crew member here).

One more thing, do not forget to make a special order of a low sodium meal in case the flight has some sort of a meal service.

Finally, each flight has a Doctor Kit, which can be opened by any doctor onboard in case of health emergencies. The kit has various medicines for common health problems that require immediate intervention, including allergies, diabetes, heart attacks and hypertension. Hopefully no one needs that.

Comment: Just to add: My Father (who is in his 60's) have similar problem, he came to U.S from India in last week of August to visit me and I told him the same thing to consult doctor before flying (as he was flying for the first time). Doctor told him that flying has nothing to do with his problem and its completely safe till the time he feels himself comfortable. But for precaution he provided him some instantly working medicine to be used only if required. Fortunately, he flew for 18 hrs. without any issue. So, consulting doctor is a best thing in your case too.